# How to convert APK to Android project (without JADX)

Tags: android, apk, project

I've lost my Android project after my Windows PC lost all my data after update.

Fortunately, I've a backup APK of my app

Is there a way to convert it to an Android project? I've tried with JADX online converter, but it gives me something useless, because classes and XMLs are completely different, and I'm back to square one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to convert it to an Android project?

The answer is **No**.

You can only decompile the APK to see the classes by [**JD-GUI**](http://jd.benow.ca/) after decompiling it with applications like [**apktool**](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) or etc but you can't just convert to actual Android Studio project since it has been compiled and so much more.

<sub>This is however depends on Progaurd or obfuscating process of the project when developing to see which classes are obfuscated and how much code you can see.</sub>